# How to develop a crypto exchange leveraging on third party API like coinbase, blockchain.com

Tags: node.js, blockchain, bitcoin, coinbase-api, cryptocurrency

I got a request as a developer to develop a bitcoin exchange site like https://mypatricia.co/ or https://instantcoins.ng/ I am to leverage on third party API like Coinbase, blockchain, it could be anything reliable API.

Users will be able to buy and sell bitcoin. For instance USER A makes an offer. USER B is interested in USER A's offer. When USER B clicks a button, with be a switch from USER A's wallet to USER B's wallet. Before the EXCHANGE is done. USER B is prompted to make payment in local currency.

I have been looking at https://developers.coinbase.com/api/v2#introduction https://api.blockchain.com/v3 I dont know how to go about it.

Is there any other better ones to work with?

There will be some other endpoints like

- Where users get list of their orders
- check wallet etc

I will appreciate your contribution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very broad topic, so I'm just going to tackle few key points.

#### Dependency on third-party blockchain data

- You can get rate limited
- You might be a subjet to a man-in-the-middle attack
- The source might (intentionally or unintentionally) send incorrect data.
- The data is usually delayed
- You'll most likely need to use another tool to create deposit addresses (since the third-party tools will allow you to create only limited amount of addresses on your account).

It's very risky and unreliable to use a third-party data. It's an industry standard to run a full node for each cryptocurrency you work with and access the blockchain data from your own node instead of a third-party API.

#### Escrowing the offered amount

As per your example, you need to make sure that **user A** is actually going to transfer the BTC. Since there are no smart contracts in BTC, you need to act as an escrow.

So you need to accept the BTC from **user A** to their deposit address (only your site should have the private key to this address) before you even allow them to pass their order into the queue.

#### Order list

Since you're going to be storing the order list on your side, you need to create a separate database and CRUD endpoints to maintain the order list.